# Named arguments in system2

Tags: r

I know I need to use the `args` argument in `system2` but I'm unable to pass the names of the arguments. I have lots of arguments that I don't wish to declare so passing a vector with ALL the arguments is not a practical choice.

I tried sending a named vector with the values being the arguments and the names being the names of the arguments but that didn't work either.

How do I specify which argument I'm declaring in `system2`?

PS: Giving the entire command in `system` seems to not work for some reason.

Comment: Can you provide sample code of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have connectivity. I want to run a command like `program -arg1 1 -arg2 2 -arg5 5` without declaring arg3 and arg4 explicitly. How do I run this from `system2`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but does `system2("program", c("-arg1", "1", "-arg2", "2", "-arg5", "5"))` work?

Comment: Wow, thanks. It works. That format seems extremely odd though.

Comment: Turns out, this also works `system2("program", c("-arg1 1", "-arg2 2", "-arg5 5"))`

Comment: Yeah ... I'm not really sure why `system2` doesn't run into problems more than it does: the difference between it and `system` is that it combines the command and arguments with a simple `paste(..., collapse=" ")`. When arguments have an embedded space, I would expect `system2` to get it right, but it looks like you'd need to quote it yourself?